# Why visitor id is null in table report_viewed_product_index Magento 2.2.6

Tags: magento2

Whenever i access product page from front-end as guest user then `visitor_id` is saving null in `report_viewed_product_index` table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento is checking Request safety that can be used to identify if current application request is safe (does not modify state) or not.

Magento prevent saving Visitor for safe methods, e.g. **GET request**

It means that for GET request magento is not setting visitor_id in that table.

You can check this function in below file.

> vendor/magento/framework/App/Request/Http.php

```
public function isSafeMethod()
{
    if ($this->isSafeMethod === null) {
        if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) && (in_array($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], $this->safeRequestTypes))) {
            $this->isSafeMethod = true;
        } else {
            $this->isSafeMethod = false;
        }
    }
    return $this->isSafeMethod;
}
```

And you can check this observer as well for more information

> vendor/magento/module-reports/Observer/CatalogProductViewObserver.php

Hope this will help you!!

Comment: The visitor must do any form submit like add to compare, newsletter subscribe etc., So then data added to customer_visitor table

Answer (score 0):

Change The Deploy mode from `Developer` To `Production`

using Command

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

Comment: after switching to production mode also not working